# Why won't my turtles breed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In my creative world in Java Edition of Minecraft, I have two turtles. I have tried to breed them multiple times, but no hearts appear. All they do is face each other and one XP point appears, nothing else.

Both of them were spawned in by me, and there's sand on the bottom of the 'pool' I have them in.

According to other websites, I've done all I need to do, but it still isn't working. I don't think that having water in the 'pool' changes anything, does it?

Answer (score 6):

Turtles have special breeding mechanics. According to the [wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Turtle#Home_beach):

> Home beach

> Each turtle remembers the beach where it hatched as its home beach. No matter how far away the turtle travels, it always eventually returns to its home beach to lay its eggs after breeding.

Thus, you can't move turtles to a new location, unless you have tools with Silk Touch in order to move the eggs they lay.

> If the player uses a tool enchanted with Silk Touch to obtain and move turtle eggs to a new location before hatching, the baby turtles remember the new hatching location as their home beach.

---

N.B: Currently, there is a bug in Bedrock Edition that prevents Turtles from laying eggs.

Comment: In particular, 'beach' must be understood as the Beach biome. Press F3 and check biome name, because the overlap between sand bars on ocean shores and the biome itself isn't 1:1. Also, " I don't think that having water in the 'pool' changes anything, does it?" - it definitely does, turtles only lay eggs on land.

Comment: Aye, but I'm assuming he's found turtles and attempted to move them @SF. Also, the "home beach" (for baby turtles) doesn't have to be a beach biome, just sand.

Comment: I'm surprised - you are right, any random sand in the overworld can allow hatching turtle eggs.